# Find html character throughout all of website and reduce size

Tags: javascript, html, string, character

Find html character and reduce size, not sure what the function is to do this?

```
 jQuery("body").children().each(function () {
    jQuery(this).html( jQuery(this).html().match("•").attr('style', "font-size:'9px'"));
 });
```

Comment: You cannot assign style to text. It has to be assigned to an element

Comment: The css has to be to element. Add div.

Comment: @roshambo Open your console, it's yelling errors. `jQuery(...).html(...).match(...).attr is not a function`.

Comment: Surely this is some function to achieve this? I have hundreds of these characters throughout this website I want to keep font size of text but reduce font size of this character. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As commented,

> You will have to set style to element and not string.

To do this, you will have to fetch the string and then wrap matched string in an element with necessary style.

---

In your code `jQuery(this).html().match("•").attr('style', "font-size:'9px'")`, `.match` will return an array of matched values. They are still string and not HTML Element.

---

**Sample**

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick(){
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if(!input) return;
  
  var p = document.querySelector("p");
  var parsed = p.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(input, "gi"), function(t){
    return "<span class='highlight'>" + t + "</span>"
  });
  p.innerHTML = parsed;
}
```

```css
.highlight{
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed gray;
}

span{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p> This is a sample Text</p>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="btn">Update Style</button>
```